# subordinate equation numbering

Tags: equations, numbering

I write this code

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial\rho_{11}}{\partial t}&=& i \Omega(rho_{12}-rho_{21}) \\  
\frac{\partial\rho_{22}}{\partial t}&=&-i \Omega(rho_{12}-rho_{21}) \\
\frac{\partial\rho_{12}}{\partial t}&=& -i \Omega \rho_{12}-i\Omega (\rho_{22}-\rho_{11})\\
\frac{\partial\rho_{21}}{\partial t}&=& -i \Omega \rho_{21}+i\Omega (\rho_{22}-\rho_{11})
 \end{eqnarray}
```

the result is like this
[image]

But I want the numbering equations be like this
(1.18a)
(1.18b)
(1.18c)
(1.18d)

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Sub-numbering equations within array](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74181/5764)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Note that it is (strongly!) recommended to use `align` rather than `eqnarray`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align?lq=1

Comment: @Werner - I don't think the current posting is a duplicate of, and is only somewhat related, to the earlier question you've located. The solutions to that posting are quite a bit more complex than what's needed for the current posting.

Answer (score 5):

First off: [Don't use the `eqnarray` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001). Use the `align` environment of the `amsmath` package instead.

Second, to achieve your specific equation numbering objective, you should use the `subequations` environment, also provided by the `amsmath` package.

Finally, I recommend you insert a `\phantom{-}` directive at the start of the right hand side (RHS) of the first equation, to better align it relative to the three other RHSs. The instruction `\phantom{-}` inserts horizontal whitespace equivalent to what would be occupied by a unary minus symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}  % just for this example
\begin{document}
\section{Some section}            % create a dummy section
\setcounter{equation}{17}         % just for this example
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\rho_{11}}{\partial t}
    &= \phantom{-}i \Omega(\rho_{12}-\rho_{21}) \\ 
\frac{\partial  \rho_{22}}{\partial t}
    &= -i \Omega(\rho_{12}-\rho_{21})\\
\frac{\partial\rho_{12}}{\partial t}
    &= -i \Omega \rho_{12}-i\Omega (\rho_{22}-\rho_{11})\\
\frac{\partial\rho_{21}}{\partial t}
    &= -i \Omega \rho_{21}+i\Omega (\rho_{22}-\rho_{11})
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```